# Error converting string to datetime on insert statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to use an Insert statement
but I am getting an error

```
INSERT INTO Temp_Table 
            ( 
             [fromDate] 
             ,[toDate] 
             ,[IDProduct] 
             ,[IDType] 
             ,[Price] 
             ,[Art] 
            ,[active]
           ) 

    VALUES (
             CAST('2013-09-28 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) 
           , CAST('2013-10-05 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) 
           , 3453 
           ,106 
           ,0 
           ,'RUN' 
           ,'' 
          )
```

The error message is in German. I can try to translate it.

```
Bei der Konvertierung eines char-Datentyps in 
einen datetime-Datentyp liegt der datetime-Wert außerhalb des gültigen Bereichs.
```

The translation is almost

```
 By Converting a Char data type in datetime Datatype lies
 the datetime value out of valid range.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass these date times in a language neutral manner `YYYMMDD hh:mm:ss.nnn` like this:

```
INSERT INTO Temp_Table 
            ( 
             [fromDate] 
             ,[toDate] 
             ,[IDProduct] 
             ,[IDType] 
             ,[Price] 
             ,[Art] 
            ,[active]
           ) 

    VALUES (
             '20130928 00:00:00.000'
            ,'20131005 00:00:00.000'
            , 3453 
            ,106 
            ,0 
            ,'RUN' 
            ,'' 
          );
```

Or just `YYYYMMDD`, like `20130928` and `20131005`; since the time parts are 0s.

Comment: Widthout CAST bring also nothing SORRY

Comment: @user160820 what is the data types of `fromDate` and `toDate`??

Comment: @user160820 - It should work fine, see this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57387/1

Comment: @user160820 - For smalldatetime pass it in this format `'YYYYMMDD hh:mm'`, see this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/acf3b/1

Answer (score 0):

No need to cast when inserting DateTime. Just write `'20130928 00:00:00'`

Comment: Sorry. Remove the dashes: `'20130928 00:00:00'`

Comment: What are the data types of `[fromDate]` and `[toDate]`?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a SQL injection attack. But there are other things that can go wrong.

Locale settings for the server may be wrong. When you configure Windows Server (and in turn SQL Server) for a specific locale, the formatting of dates and times are inherited automatically from those settings.

If the locale settings don't match the data being passed to the server -- for instance, if dates are passed as *MM/DD/YYYY* when they should be *DD/MM/YYYY*  then the error will result. It can also happen if you're trying to import data from a source where the **date formatting clashes..**